# Laravel - Saving to pivot table in many to many relationship with extra column

Tags: php, laravel

I have models `Transaction` and `Option`, that have many to many relationship. The pivot table `transaction_options` has columns `transaction_id`, `option_id` and `price`.
I have defined the relationships in the models like this:

**Transaction** model:

```
public function options()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Option', 'transaction_options')->withPivot('price');
}
```

**Option** model:

```
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Transaction', 'transaction_options')->withPivot('price');
}
```

I am wondering how can I save something in the pivot table, I have tried something like this, but it is not working:

```
   foreach($data->options as $option) {
        $transaction->options()->create([
            'transaction_id' => $transaction->id,
            'extras_id'      => $option->extraId,
            'option_id'      => $option->id,
            'price'          => $option->price
        ]);
    }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass the extra field as a value to attach function

```
$transaction->options()->attach([$request['id'] => ['price' => $request['price']]]);
```

Answer (score 7):

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

From what I can see, you should use your code like this:

```
foreach ($data->options as $option) {
    $transaction->options()->attach($option->id, ['price' => $option->price])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass pivot data as the second parameter:

```
foreach($data->options as $option) {
    $transaction->options()->create(
        ['extras_id' => $option->extraId],
        ['price' => $option->price]
    );
}
```

You also don't need to pass both `transaction_id` and `option_id`, they will be inserted automatically.